# couldn't install gems - Gem not found Exception

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, rvm

os: os x lion

i was not able to install any gems . checked the gem sources http://rubygems.org was in the list. tried using the system gem (ruby 1.8.7) and rvm ruby (1.9.2). For any gem install GemNotFoundException was thrown.

```
gem install sinatra --no-ri --no-rdoc
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'sinatra' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: sinatra
SKYLINE:rubygems-1.8.6 avinash$ gem sources
*** CURRENT SOURCES ***

http://rubygems.org/
```

Any ideas?

Help would be appreciated.

-Avinash

Comment: when using the system ruby, did you run it with sudo? It is bizarre that it doesn't find Sinatra and then suggests Sinatra as a possible alternative.

Comment: like when you google 'recursion'

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't be simply that you are not connected to the internet when trying to download the gem ? ... (I had the same, it looks stupid, but it happens ;